# Autodesk Forge modern conversion method IFC 2x3 creates model twice

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, ifc

I have a IFC 2x3 format model, that I want to render using Autodesk Forge viewer. When I switched from "legacy" (Navisworks) to "modern" (Revit) conversion, the model needs a long time to finish loading in the viewer and it is rendered twice. Here is a screenshot, how it looks now:

[image: model rendered twice]

When the model is converted using legacy conversion method, the model is rendered correctly as one. Also, other IFC viewers render the model correctly:

[image: viewer example 1]
[image: viewer example 2]

Is there an issue with modern conversion method and IFC 2x3 files? Other 2x3 IFC models are rendered correctly, but as stated in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876164/forge-ifc-model-weird-shadow-lines), I have issues with another 2x3 IFC file which may be related.

On the supported formats [website](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/), there is only stated, that IFC is supported, but not which exact versions.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Hi Toni, This looks like an issue with the conversion engine, I'll enquire with the engineering team on this. please wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876164/forge-ifc-model-weird-shadow-lines), the problem seems to be the IfcSite. After replacing longitude, latitude and elevation with '$', the model is rendered nicely. The modern conversion seems to have issues with the geographic reference point of IfcSite, altough it is only given for informational purposes ([Link](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC2x/ADD1/HTML/ifcproductextension/lexical/ifcsite.html#:%7E:text=The%20standard%20geometric%20representation%20of,used%20to%20constrain%20the%20triangulation.)).

[image: correctly rendered model]